# Location of BSOD report

Tags: windows-10, bsod

When a computer experiences a BSOD, an entry is added to the Event Log, such as:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff96000015de8,
>   0xfffff88007db9fb0, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. **Report Id: 080210-24819**

Where can the report be found?

Comment: There is no report. You have a DMP file. Try using Nirsoft Blue Screen View to read it and see if it interprets the error for you.

Comment: _Bug Check 0x3B: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
The SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION bug check has a value of 0x0000003B.
This bug check appears very infrequently._. c0000005 is the code for trying to access non existent memory - a programming error.. The Instruction at memory address 0xfffff88007db9fb0 tried to write to address 0. 0 to 64K is null so the programmer tried to create something and didn't check that it worked, then tried to use it.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x3b--system-service-exception

Comment: Also in Control Panel see **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Problem Reports**. Double click your report.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a report but a dump file that needs to be debugged to find the cause

2 Places dumps are found

> C:\Windows\  if configured for a Kernel dump
>
> C:\Windows\minidump   if configured for small dump

it will be a file with extension .DMP